# Mover elementos da direita para a esqueda, nav

Tags: html, css

Senhores, ótimo dia,
Por favor, estou trabalhando em um projeto particular, e indo aos pouco criando a página.
Quero colocar os lis para a direita, porém com esse codígo não consigo, as documentações dizem que funcionária, mas ainda não achei a solução.
Como poderia proceder?

Esse é o html e css:

```html
    <nav class="content">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
```

```css
.content ul {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    
    display: inline-flex;
   
}
content ul li {
    list-style-type: none;

    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: baseline;
    align-content: flex-end;
    
    margin: 0 1em;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, nessa classe faltou o "**.**" `content ul li {` deveria ser `.content ul li {` e ainda tem uma `div` de fechamento no meio do código `</div>`, me parecei desnecessária...

Depois vc está colocando estilos de alinhamento de container que deveria estar no **PAI** no **FILHO**, ai não da certo mesmo... e vc ainda usou estilos de `align` para alinha no eixo `X`, mas no eixo `X` se alinha com `margin` ou `justify`

Bom, existe mais de uma opção para fazer esse alinhamento, mas aqui tem uma sugestão. **Tudo que era desnecessário no seu CSS eu deixei comentado**

```css
.content ul {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;

  /* display: inline-flex; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;

}

.content ul li {
  list-style-type: none;

  /* flex-direction: row; */
  /* flex-wrap: nowrap; */
  /* justify-content: flex-end; */
  /* align-items: baseline; */
  /* align-content: flex-end; */

  margin: 0 1em;

}
```

```html
<nav class="content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Caramba Muito obrigado. A div foi sem querer no código desculpe, é bem mais simples do que a forma tentei. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @AlbertyLucas sem problemas meu caro, as coisas com CSS costumam ser mais simples do que a gente pensa...